# R: Populating a list from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am slowly learning how to work with apply and which statements in r but am still kind of failing at life overall.

I have a data frame, df, with 4 columns (in reality my dataset is comprised of many dates over several years, with several thousand user_ids):

```
    >df
   id  timestamp user_id app_version    
1  96 2013-03-05    12        1.05
2  99 2013-03-05    32       1.0.5
3  02 2013-03-05    21        1.05
4  14 2013-03-05    21       1.0.5
5  16 2013-03-05    12       1.0.5
6  32 2013-03-06    32       1.0.3
7  33 2013-03-06    33       1.0.3
8  37 2013-03-06    12       1.0.3
9  39 2013-03-06    21       1.0.3
10 40 2013-03-06    12       1.0.5
```

And a vector, app:
>app<-c("1.0.3","1.0.5","2.05")

My end goal is to calculate the average number of times a user logs in per day (ie the average of the count of entries a user has with the same timestamp) divided up by version number (eg. for app version 1.05 users have an average of 3 log ins per day on 2013-03-05). I can do this manually via `df[which(df$app_version="1.05"),]`. But I'd like to loop through my app vector and have a list of data frames at the end, one data frame for each app version, where each data frame contains dates as the rows and avg. number of logins as the columns). The code below is my approach, but my final list is not correct, as it is a list of two numbers, not two data frames.

```
require(reshape2)    
require(dplyr)    
require(lubridate)
df$timestamp <- as.Date(df$timestamp)  # Converting to date


# Step 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parsing data into different dataframes for each app version
flist<-vector(mode="list",length=length(app))
fdts<-vector(mode="list",length=length(app))
for (i in 1:length(app)){
  appdat<-df[which(df$app_version==app[i]),]  

# Step 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Creating table of timestamps as columns, with user_ids making up row
tmp.ndat<-dcast(appdat,id~timestamp,value.var="user_id",drop=TRUE)

# Step 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
# Createing contingency tables of each day
ctable.day<-apply(tmp.ndat[,-1],2,table)

# Step 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculating the avg and stdev for each user for each day 
dts<-as.Date(names(ctable.day))
avg.day<-lapply(ctable.day,mean)
sd.day<-lapply(ctable.day,sd)

# Step 5 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# Combine all averages and stdevs, with timestamp as rows and app version as columns
tmp<-cbind(avg.day,sd.day)
tmp.dts<-as.Date(names(ctable.day))

flist[i]<-tmp
fdts[i]<-tmp.dts
}
return(flist)
```

Comment: it is unclear what are you trying to do . Also you talk about 2013-06-05 date that don't exist in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems like you want the average number of logins by user, for each day, with each app_version in a different data frame. So if on a given day you had 3 users log in to an app, and they logged in 1,5, and 8 times respectively, then the average would be (1+5+8)/3. If this is incorrect let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Here's one way to do this:

```
df$counts <- 1
# tmp$count contains number of logins by each user for each app for each day
tmp <- aggregate(counts~user_id+timestamp+app_version,df,sum)
get.stats <- function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
result <- lapply(split(tmp,tmp$app_version),
             function(dat)aggregate(counts~timestamp+app_version,dat,get.stats))
result <- lapply(result,function(r)with(r,data.frame(timestamp,app_version,counts)))
result
# $`1.0.3`
#    timestamp app_version mean sd
# 1 2013-03-06       1.0.3    1  0
#
# $`1.0.5`
#    timestamp app_version mean sd
# 1 2013-03-05       1.0.5    1  0
# 2 2013-03-06       1.0.5    1 NA
# 
# $`1.05`
#    timestamp app_version mean sd
# 1 2013-03-05        1.05    1  0
```

This code creates a dummy column, `df$counts` which is needed for the next step. Then we aggregate by `user_id`, `timestamp`, and `app_version` to calculate the number of logins by each user for each app on each day. Then we use `lapply(split(df,df$app_version), FUN)` to  split `df` by `app_version` and apply the function to each subset. The function aggregates `counts` by timestamp (and `app_version`, but there's only one in a given subset), to calculate mean and sd.

The results with your sample data are fairly uninteresting because no user logs in more than once for a given app on a given day, so the means are all = 1.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The use of `aggregate()` was key here and it works much faster than other solutions since I'm not reading things into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you're trying to do is fairly vague. For example, you mention wanting an average for each date, but an average of what? Do you mean the count as opposed to the average? From what I understood, this seems like an ideal use case for the split-apply-combine method, using a function from the `apply` family. Specifically, `tapply`. You need to run `tapply`, and have it apply the function across dataframes that are subsetted according to your version column AND your date column. What I would do is first split the whole thing according to version, getting a list of data frames back. Then go through and do a `tapply` to every entry in that list.